# Why doesn't this ProgressDialog show?

Tags: android, progressdialog

It's in a method in the Activity.

```
if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
progressDialog.show();
```

I've tried all combinations of dismissing and destroying the dialog. The `mActivity` variable refers to the right activity. I've also tried wrapping it in a `runOnUIThread()` method. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: call progressDialog.create()

Comment: Y do u want to add style to ur pDialog.. is it crashing??

Comment: @KhizarHayat That didn't work

Comment: @DJphy it doesn't crash and there is no warning or error in logcat. It just doesn't show.

Comment: On which android version  you are using. See my answer  i use this and doing well

Comment: @KhizarHayat I'm testing it on both an Android 6.0 phone and an Android 4.2.2 phone. Neither one shows the ProgressDialog.

Comment: Test my code i uploaded in my answer

Comment: remove the R.style.ProgressDialogTheme. I suspect that/ paste that code here (style code);

Answer (score 0):

```
 ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage(message);
            if(title != null){
                progress.setTitle(title);
            }
            progress.setCancelable(true);
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                progress.create();
            }
            progress.show();
```

Comment: It will work in fragment. if you want to show in anctivity then replace getActivity() with this.